# Как вывести элементы двух моделей в одном списке? RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем две модели `Video` и `Picture`. Как вывести на странице видео и картинки вперемешку, в одном списке, отсортировав их по дате?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите **хорошо** и **рельсово** – готовьтесь к крупным изменениям.

Я полагаю, что вы хотите достать их отсортированными средствами БД: так вы получаете целый ряд очень вкусных возможностей. Пытаться пользоваться для этого двумя разными таблицами – смертоубийство, ActiveRecord будет всеми силами противиться.

Здесь я покажу два трюка: STI и `render` "неоднородной" коллекции.

Из вышенаписанного напрашивается вывод: делать нужно одной таблицей. [Это, впрочем, не означает, что модель должна быть одна](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79630/). Добавив поле `type` (типа `string`) к своей таблице, вы получите очень занятное поведение – ActiveRecord будет в этом поле сохранять название класса модели, и при запросах будет его соблюдать. То есть, если у вас есть такие классы:

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
class Video < Media
class Photo < Media
```

Первый класс создаётся, как обычно – не забудьте только дать ему все поля, что есть **и** у `Video`, **и** у `Photo`. А класс `Video` можно сделать хоть руками – ему не нужна миграция. Но если пользоваться генератором, то так:

```
rails g model Video --no-migration --parent Media
```

...то запрос на `Media.all` вовсе необязательно вернёт именно коллекцию объектов `Media`. Причём система будет следить, чтобы в поле `type` были только названия базового класса (который, собственно, владеет таблицей) и его наследников (непосредственных и не очень). Если туда вписать что-то неправильное, будет ошибка при попытке инстанцировать объект.

А теперь самое вкусное. Сделав вышеобозначенные классы и убедившись, что они хранятся в одной и той же таблице (по генерируемым запросам), сделайте в контроллере это:

```
@medias = Media.all # Потом вы это захотите разбить на страницы.
                    # Это можно. Потом.
```

Где-нибудь в виде выведите эту коллекцию следующим образом:

```
render @medias # Ну, а как ещё...
```

...добавьте partial'ы, которые он будет просить в сообщениях об ошибках и **возрадуйтесь**.

Comment: Спасибо, это лучший ответ который я когда либо получал по рельсам!